# Sort Only One Element Of KeyValuePair inside List<t>

Tags: c#, list

I have the following implementation

```
public static List<KeyValuePair<int, double>> entries = new List<KeyValuePair<int, double>>();
entries.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, double>(j, min));
```

For some mathematical computation, I want to sort only this `min value` and not the `j key`. 
How can this be done?
Thanks.

EDIT: I am using class level variables and I tried this repeatedly

```
PSOLib.entries = PSOLib.entries.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value).ToList();
lineChart.DataContext = PSOLib.entries;
```

and the values simple don't get sorted. Where did I screw?

Comment: `entries.OrderBy(o => o.Value)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
entries = entries.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: I am using class level variable, `PSOLib.entries = PSOLib.entries.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value).ToList();
            lineChart.DataContext = PSOLib.entries;` and the values simple don't get sorted. i have tried this.

Comment: Are you sure the lineChart doesn't then resort them? If it's a third party control, it very well may. Put a breakpoint after setting entries and inspect whether or not they've been sorted.

Answer (score 1):

```
entries.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value)
```

or

```
entries.Sort((l, r) => l.Value.CompareTo(r.Value));
```